# How to limit Nifi processor to run on a single node in cluster?

Tags: apache-nifi

We are building a data workflow with NiFi and want the final (custom) processor (which runs the deduplication logic) to run only one one of the NiFi cluster nodes (instead of running on all of them). I see that NiFi 1.7.0 (which is not yet released) has a `PrimaryNodeOnly` annotation to enforce a single node execution behaviour. Is there a way or workaround to enforce such behaviour in NiFi 1.6.0?

NOTE: In addition to `@PrimaryNodeOnly`, it would be better if NiFi provides a way to run a processor on a single node only (i.e., some annotation like `@SingleNodeOnly`). This way the execution node need not necessarily be the primary node which therefore will reduce the load on primary node. This is just an ask for future and not necessary to solve the problem mentioned above.

Comment: Do you want to run only one instance of the processor at the same time with no need to assign it to a particular node, or you want it to run always on the same node every time?

Comment: We want to run on one instance of the processor at the same time with no need to assign it to a particular node. No, we don't want to run it always on the same node.

Comment: In that case setting the processor to run on `Primary Node` would be enough. BTW, the `PrimaryNodeOnly` annotation is for developers who write processors to restrict the processor's execution strategy to be `Primary`. Dataflow designer/developer can't change the strategy to `All Nodes` through UI or API.

Comment: @janeshs in that case, in the SCHEDULING tab of processor configuration, if you keep default Scheduling strategy (Timer driven) and set "**Concurrent Tasks**" to 1 you will have only one instance of the processor running at ounce.

Comment: @RadhwaneChebaane - "Concurrent task configuration is per node" as mentioned by Matt Clarke in [https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/52112/nifi-load-distribution-in-getfile-processor.html](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/52112/nifi-load-distribution-in-getfile-processor.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific workaround to enforce it in previous versions, it is on the data flow designer to mark the intended processor(s) to run on the Primary Node only. You could write a script to query the NiFi API for processors of certain types or names, then check/set the strategy as Primary Node Only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer [mattyb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668575/mattyb). What is the usual way to mark the intended processor to run only on primary node in NiFI 1.6.0 through data flow designer? Is this done by defining remote process groups with input/output ports and connecting to them from the parent or root-level group? Regarding the script you mentioned in your answer - Is the script for use with 1.6.0 or 1.7.0 version of NiFi?

Comment: A script would call the NiFi REST API to configure the processor. Check the API documentation on how to set the execution strategy for a processor. It should be the same for 1.6.0 and 1.7.0 IIRC.

Comment: To do it manually in the UI, right click on the processor and on the Scheduling tab, choose Primary Node Only for the execution strategy option in the top left corner. Note that only source processors (those with no input connections) should be marked as Primary Node Only

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications [mattyb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668575/mattyb). We want to run the very last processor (deduplication) in a workflow to run on a single node. Given this is not a source processor, is there another way to limit the number of nodes to one?

Comment: What do you mean by "limit the number of nodes to 1"? When you configure the `Execution Strategy` to `Primary`, it will only run on the primary node. If some issues happen and the primary node goes down, the new primary node automatically takes care of the work.

Comment: Why does deduplication have to run on a single node? For example if you're using DetectDuplicate and all nodes use the same DistributedMapCacheServer, then it should have the same effect. For your custom processor you will likely want to use something similar, or if you know there will rarely be duplicates, you can use CLUSTER-scoped State Management in your processor to store the values. I recommend the former and not the latter solution, as storing many (or large) values in processor state can degrade Zookeeper and the entire NiFi cluster.

Answer (score 2):

In NiFi 1.6.0 it's possible and looks like this:

[image]

[image]